# How to build a list of two strings by iteratively combining variable names stored in a data frame so that there is one from each column

Tags: r

I have a set of tasks with sub-variables, the names of which I have put in a data frame:

```
A tibble: 8 x 3
  AB                                            PRP              DUAL                   
  <chr>                                         <chr>            <chr>                  
1  Combined_t2|t1_lag8                          mean_RT_200_all   dual_average_accuracy
2  Combined_abmag_t2_lag8_minus_lag3            mean_RT_1000_all  mean_RT_dual     
3  Combined_abmag_t2_1.0_minus_lag3             PRP               Dual_cost            
4  Combined_abwidth                             NA                NA                    
5  Combined_abdepth                             NA                NA                    
6  Combined_lag3vslag8_residuals                NA                NA                    
7  Combined_lag3vslag8_stdrdized_residuals      NA                NA
```

I would like to combine these variable names, one from each column, two at a time into a list.
so it would look like:

```
"Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "mean_RT_200_all"
"Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "mean_RT_1000_all"
"Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "PRP"
...
"Combined_abwidth" "dual_average_accuracy"
"Combined_abwidth" "mean_RT_dual"
...
"PRP" "Dual_cost"
"PRP" "dual_average_accuracy"
...
```

I have tried the "combn" function, but that seems to just work for lists, not data frames. Also tried some 'for' loops but no success.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want every combination of 2 variables pulled one each from the 3 columns?

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: With only 3 columns, it would be pretty easy to do (all combinations of AB and PRP) + (all combinations of AB and DUAL) + (all combinations of PRP and DUAL). But this would scale poorly - if you had even one more column it would be a pain. Do you need a solution that scales up to more columns?

Comment: no, the most I will have will be three tasks which will be combined, so only three columns of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `base` solution that is general (scales up to more columns). Calling your data `dd`:

```
# Omit missing values - data isn't really rectangular
# and rows seem to have no meaning
# so a list is an appropriate structure
dd_list = lapply(dd, na.omit)

# generate all pairs of "columns" (now list items)
col_pairs = combn(seq_along(dd_list), 2)

# for each pair, use `expand.grid` to generate all combinations
# since the wanted result is a list of vectors, not a data frame
# we strip the names and convert to matrix
result = apply(col_pairs, MARGIN = 2, FUN = function(x) {
  as.matrix(unname(do.call(expand.grid, args = dd_list[x])))
})

# bind the matrices together - this seems like a nice result to work with
result = do.call(rbind, result)
result
 #      [,1]                                      [,2]                   
 # [1,] "Combined_t2|t1_lag8"                     "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [2,] "Combined_abmag_t2_lag8_minus_lag3"       "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [3,] "Combined_abmag_t2_1.0_minus_lag3"        "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [4,] "Combined_abwidth"                        "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [5,] "Combined_abdepth"                        "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [6,] "Combined_lag3vslag8_residuals"           "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [7,] "Combined_lag3vslag8_stdrdized_residuals" "mean_RT_200_all"      
 # [8,] "Combined_t2|t1_lag8"                     "mean_RT_1000_all"   
 # ...

  
# but if you really want a list we can `split` the matrix into 
# individual rows:
split(result, 1:nrow(result))
# $`1`
# [1] "Combined_t2|t1_lag8" "mean_RT_200_all"    
# 
# $`2`
# [1] "Combined_abmag_t2_lag8_minus_lag3" "mean_RT_200_all"                  
# 
# $`3`
# [1] "Combined_abmag_t2_1.0_minus_lag3" "mean_RT_200_all"                 
# ...
```

The above is fancy (and scalable) way to do it - it's pretty much equivalent to this quick and dirty method:

```
result = rbind(
  expand.grid(x = na.omit(dd$AB), y = na.omit(dd$PRP)),
  expand.grid(x = na.omit(dd$AB), y = na.omit(dd$DUAL)),
  expand.grid(x = na.omit(dd$PRP), y = na.omit(dd$DUAL))
)

split(as.matrix(unname(result)), 1:nrow(result))
```

Comment: Quick question, how would I make it a combination of 3 variable names rather than 2?

Comment: That's much easier, `do.call(expand.grid(dd_list))`, or `expand.grid(na.omit(dd$AB), na.omit(dd$PRP), na.omit(dd$DUAL))`. The `expand.grid` function gives you all combinations of the inputs. Your example was complicated because you *didn't* want all 3.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1. Save each column you want as a separate dataframe with the columns labeled "variable".
2. Add a column of increasing odd numbers to the first dataframe (start with 1 and add 2 for each row) and label that row "ID".
3. Add a column of increasing even numbers to the second dataframe (start with 2 and add 2 for each row) and label that row "ID".
4. Combine both dataframes using `tidyverse::bind_rows`
5. Use `tidyverse::arange`to sort by "ID".
6. Use `tidyverse::select` to choose only the column labeled "variable".
7. Save the resulting dataframe as your final dataframe.

Quick and dirty solution. I'm sure there are fancier ways to do this out there. But this will get the job done until that answer comes.